# Unable to successfully execute some commands in Cygwin

Tags: windows, cygwin

I installed Cygwin64 in my 64-bit Windows 7 machine. The following commands failed executing, however, by displaying the error messages below. Could you help providing a resolution please?

```
$ ll
-bash: ll: command not found

$ clear
-bash: clear: command not found
```

However, the command ls -l worked...

```
$ ls -l
total 0
```

Also i tried by un-commenting the following line in .bashrc file in my home dir -

```
# alias ll='ls -l'
```

But it didn't help either!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After you uncomment the alias, you should start a new Cygwin shell for it to take effect. The `.bashrc` file is actually a script that is sourced when bash starts.

`clear` is not a Cygwin (Unix) command. Just use Ctrl-L instead.